# Using static file in extended template in Django

Tags: python, django, django-1.8

I have  basic template "header.html", I am trying to extend it to get some new data using **extend** tag of django.

header.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load staticfiles %}
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,500' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'style.css' %}"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'font-awesome.min.css.css' %}"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'bootstrap.min.css' %}"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'jquery-ui.css' %}"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/buttons.css' %}"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/jquery.switchButton.css' %}"/>
<script src="{% static 'jquery-1.11.3.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'jquery-ui.js.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'jquery.dataTables.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'dataTables.bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'common.js' %}"></script>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<div id="header">
    <div id='topMenuDiv'>
        <a href='/search' class='fa '>BROWSE MOVIES</a>
    </div>
</div>
</head>
<body>
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

and I have home.html

```
{% extends "header.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <script src="{% static 'index.js' %}"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

Now, this would work if I include {% load staticfiles %} in home.html, while gives an error - Invalid block tag: 'static' without it.
What I want to know is there a way to include static file "index.js" without using {% load staticfiles %} as this would load static files again.

Comment: Which Django version are you using?

Comment: Django version = 1.8.7

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`{% load staticfiles %}` is only loading the code for template tag library `staticfiles`. It's not loading all static files into the django template. The template tag `static` is part of the `staticfiles` template tag library, so django template needs to know where is the code for `static` coming from.

You could call `load` on any template tag, even your custom ones. It's like the pseudo code `from staticfiles import static` in python.

Please look at [django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#load) for details.

Comment: Yeah, I agree. I don't think that staticfiles is loaded several times -- I think that the template is constructed according to the extends tag and only then the staticfiles are loaded.

Comment: But what I am trying to do is add another staticfile (index.js) from the same location, so load wouldn't serve my purpose.

Comment: No, I've already told you, `load` does not load static files, `load` only loads the template tag `static` so you can do `{% static 'xyz' %}` wherever you like in your current page.

Comment: Here's what `static` does: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#static

Comment: Yes thanks. So {% load static from staticfiles %} would work for my purpose I guess?

Comment: Just do `{% load staticfiles %}` then you can use `{% static 'index.js ' %}` to access `index.js` as long as your `index.js` is in your `STATICFILES_STORAGE` directory.

Comment: Yes, but won't it be like importing whole nltk while I can do from nltk import nltk.something

Comment: When python load some module, it only does it once. So yes, it's going to load `staticfiles` module, but what's your concern?

Comment: As far as I know, there is only `{% static %}` tag in staticfiles, so it won't matter if you load whole thing or just one tag.